# @property from*.h does not show up in *.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I am very interested in app-programming and so I started programming apps for the iphone with Todd Moore's book. I want to recreate the first example in his book.
Therefore i need to some properties in my ViewController.m which i declared in ViewController.h like this via the drag function "New Referencing Outlet":

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *antwort;
- (IBAction)antworte:(id)sender;
```

My problem is that this is not shown in ViewController.m. Can you help me maybe?
Best regards!

Comment: what does "not show up" mean?

Comment: What do you mean "this is not shown in ViewController.m"? What did you expect to see? What did you actually see? What do you think that difference means?

Answer (score 5):

It won't actually appear in your .m file, but you should still be able to use them from there. (If the book is from a few years ago, it may show code that used to be placed in the .m file for outlets, but that code is no longer needed.)

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your `Foo.m` file there should be this line: `#import "Foo.h"`

That means the *entire contents* of `Foo.h` is copy/pasted into `Foo.m` before the code gets compiled.

So, as far as the compiler is concerned, your @property/IBAction/etc code is in fact inside the `Foo.m` file.

Also, the book might be designed for an older version of Xcode. In old versions of Xcode things behaved a bit differently. If the book talks about `@synthesize label` being in the *.m file, ignore that. In older versions of the Objective-C language that was required but these days it usually is not needed (there are still some times when you need it, but they're rare). Just don't do `@synthesize` and ask here on stack overflow if you get a compile error that looks like it needs to be fixed with `@synthesize`. We'll show you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to your properties as instance attributes:

```
self.label.text = @"hello";
self.antwort.text = @"bar";
```

Or directly:

```
_label.text = @"hello";
_antwort.text = @"bar";
```

PS: Assuming you are using Xcode 5 where you don't have to explicitly call @syntesize.